# asort() in php using two strings in an array

Tags: php, sorting

Array
(
    [0] => John Smith
)

Array
(
    [0] => Mary Smith
)

Array
(
    [0] => Jack Sparrow
)

I want to sort the following arrays according to its first name, (John,Mary,Smith)

However this return `111`

```
$araySort = array($r['fullname']);
                        $sort = asort($araySort, SORT_REGULAR);
                        echo "<pre>";   
                        print_r($sort); 
                        echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

[`asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) modifies the array by reference and returns `true` (1) on success. You want to accumulate all the names in the loop then call the function.